# 'aws s3 ls' command was hanging until setting default region

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I created setup show in the image in  region Oregon (us-west-2) ,and I was sure that everything was in place correctly , then I tried to do `aws s3 ls` from the ec2 in the private subnet , it was hanging and not giving me and out put. after few search I have created ~/.aws/config file and added the default region as below.

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
```

and things started to work , Now I have 2 questions on this.

1. When the setup created from the VPC and region is decided for the whole infrastructure on that stage it self, and why do we need to specify a default region for an ec2 instance which is created inside the VPC ?? appreciate if some one can clarify this.
2. I have created this setup using terraform , to setup this default region, do I really need to use userdata for ec2 instance or is there any other way to make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of AWS CLI you use. In v2 it should work the way you expect without additional config required:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/486